Issue with match_phrase_prefix Query for Certain Asset Numbers in OpenSearch
I am using OpenSearch version 7.10.2 and encountering an issue with the match_phrase_prefix query on certain asset numbers. My asset_number field is analyzed using a lowercase analyzer. Here is the detailed setup:
Index Settings:
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_routing": {
      "required": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "asset_number": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Problem Description
I have an index with asset_number values and am trying to run a match_phrase_prefix query to fetch assets starting with specific prefixes. The query works for some prefixes but not for others. Here are the results

Working: PB1234, PE1234, PG1234, PI1234, PJ1234, PK1234, PL1234, PM1234, PN1234, AH1234, BH1234
Not working: PC1234, PD1234, PF1234, PH1234, AC1234, BC1234, AD1234, BD1234, CA1234, CB1234, CC1234, CD1234, CE1234, DA1234, DB1234, DC1234, FA1234

The query is supposed to match asset numbers that start with specific prefixes like "PC", "PD", etc., but it fails for many of them. But when I try to search for pc1 or pd1, I am getting the result
Query Used
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "asset_number": "pc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Any suggestions on what might be causing the query to fail for specific prefixes, I want to know the actual reason behind it. Because the same data and same query is working perfectly fine in local env or staging env ?
Additional Information:

OpenSearch version: 7.10.2
Lucene version: 9.4.2
Query works for some prefixes but not others even though they are in the same index.


I am not sure if this will help, but I tried to do this and it worked for me:
First adding an index with mapping and analyzer
PUT /stacktest
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_routing": {
      "required": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "asset_number": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Then adding the data (with routing)
POST /stacktest/_doc/PB1234?routing=PB1234
{
  "asset_number": "PB1234"
}

POST /stacktest/_doc/PE1234?routing=PE1234
{
  "asset_number": "PE1234"
}

POST /stacktest/_doc/PG1234?routing=PG1234
{
  "asset_number": "PG1234"
}

POST /stacktest/_doc/PI1234?routing=PI1234
{
  "asset_number": "PI1234"
}
.
.
.

Then doing the search
GET /stacktest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "asset_number": "pc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Here is the result:
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2.9618306,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stacktest",
        "_id": "PC1234",
        "_score": 2.9618306,
        "_routing": "PC1234",
        "_source": {
          "asset_number": "PC1234"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

The search worked for all the cases, I feel that your data is not inserted in the index, maybe wrong routing or something, because your query looks totally correct, and I tested it and it is working correctly.
my answer is not too helpful but it may tell you that the problem is not the query, it is somewhere else.

I want to understand what is the possible reason, because same query working fine on my local machine or other lower env except production

I have no idea, but I feel that the data is not inserted already this is why you are not getting it, try to check if it is inserted in the index, run match all, and check it.

Data is there because when I try to search for pc1 or pd1,  then I am getting the result of same document
